# A test for quantifier elimination

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, quantifier-elimination

In David Marker's "Model Theory: An Introduction" book I was trying to prove Corollary 3.1.12 which is left for the reader, but I couldn't reach any solution. The aforementioned corollary states:

Suppose that $T$ is an $\mathcal{L}-$theory such that:

$i)$ $T$ has algebraically prime models, and

$ii)$ $\mathcal{M}\prec_{s}\mathcal{N}$ whenever $\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ are models of T;

Then $T$ has quantifier elimination.

Would be thankful for your help.

Comment: I found the proof [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/model_theory_notes.pdf) on page 13. The author notes that the "proof is very long" and "[he] has yet to internalize it". Maybe someone else has a shorter proof

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Marker is offering this as a corollary to his Theorem 3.1.9 which states that the theory DAG of torsion-free divisible abelian groups has quantifier elimination. It isn't really a corollary, but rather a generalisation: Marker has tried to help in the text before the corollary by identifying the lemmas that prove *(i)* and *(ii)* in the special case of DAG, but is expecting you to figure out how these lemmas are used in the proof of Theorem 3.1.9. He has made this a bit harder for you by only referring explicitly to one of the two lemmas in that proof.

The idea is that *(i)* generalises the existence of divisible hulls and *(ii)* generalises the property that if $G \subseteq H$ is an inclusion of DAGs and $H \models \exists y\phi(\overline{g}, y)$, where $\phi(\overline{x}, y)$ is quantifier-free and $\overline{g} \in G$, then $G \models \exists y\phi(\overline{G}, y)$.